# Can Photo viewer only crop to the aspect ratio of the original image

Tags: photo-editing, photos

I find it puzzling that every time I've cropped an image with Photo Viewer, I'm unable to change the aspect ratio of the crop region (it remains the same as the aspect ratio of the original image). I'm not sure whether Photo Viewer on elementary is the same as the Shotwell Photo Viewer on Ubuntu, which has a small configuration popup when cropping, but the app looks very similar, so I'm thinking the configuration popup should be accessible somewhere? Or if the app isn't the same, is it meant to be this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aspect ratio can be changed:

[image]

[image]

To enable it, try running this command:

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.yorba.shotwell.crop-settings
```

[Image Source](https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/bear_brown_wet_sits_toed_94311_3840x2400.jpg)

Comment: Why this isn't enabled by default is beyond me, but thanks for the answer - it worked perfectly!

Comment: Hi I have tried `gsettings reset-recursively org.yorba.shotwell.crop-settings` and it says `No such schema 'org.yorba.shotwell.crop-settings'`

Comment: Hi @IvanVilanculo sorry for the delay in replying. I've not got eOS installed right now so give me an hour or two to check. Can you confirm which version of Elementary OS you installed, and when did you install?

Answer (score 5):

On elementary OS Loki 0.4, I solved the problem by installing dconf-editor

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then with dconf-editor navigate to org/panthenon/photos/crop-settings and set `last-crop-height`, `last-crop-menu-choice` and `last-crop-height` values to `0`.
Please note it should be exactly zero otherwise it will not work!